# Magento 2.1 : How can I use a uiComponent in my custom modules' modal (adminhtml)

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, uicomponent

I'm creating a module, and part of this module is that it adds a modal (slide-out) on the product edit page in the adminhtml. I've got it so far working that the modal shows, but now I'm faced with the next challenge: get a grid of my custom entity to show in this modal. (you know, just like when you want to set the related products, you get a slide panel that allows you to select entities). How can I make this? Can anyone point me in the right direction? I'm currently looking at uiComponents, but Magento 2.1's documentation isn't quite complete yet.

Comment: Hi Geil.did u got the solution for slide out .i too have to implement in my custome module

Comment: Any luck Giel ?